# JAVA linux KeyListener seems not working

Tags: java, events, listener, keylistener, keyevent

i'm working on JAVA snake game and it seems my KeyListener not working for some reason. I tried to look for answers but i couldnt find anything helpful. I'm beginner in JAVA so i dont know if i'm using the keylistener properly. I got no output at all.

```
public class GameBoard extends JPanel implements Runnable, KeyListener{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private boolean up, down, right, left; 

    private Thread thread;
    private boolean running;
    private long targetTime;

    public GameBoard() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH,HEIGHT));
        setFocusable(true);
        requestFocus(); 
        addKeyListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int k = e.getKeyCode();
        System.out.println("pressed");
        if( k == KeyEvent.VK_W || k == KeyEvent.VK_UP) up = true;
        if( k == KeyEvent.VK_S || k == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) down = true;
        if( k == KeyEvent.VK_A || k == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) left = true;
        if( k == KeyEvent.VK_D || k == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) right = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        int k = e.getKeyCode();
        System.out.println("Released");
        if( k == KeyEvent.VK_W || k == KeyEvent.VK_UP) up = false;
        if( k == KeyEvent.VK_S || k == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) down = false;
        if( k == KeyEvent.VK_A || k == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) left = false;
        if( k == KeyEvent.VK_D || k == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) right = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        int k = e.getKeyCode();
        System.out.println("typed");
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(running) return;
        init();
        while(running) {
            startTime = System.nanoTime();

            update();
            requestRender();


            elapsed = System.nanoTime()-startTime;
            wait = targetTime - elapsed / 10000000;
            if (wait > 0) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(wait);
                }catch(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void init() {
        addKeyListener(this);
    }


    private void update() {

            if(up && dy == 0) {
                dy = -SIZE;
                dx = 0;
            }
            if(down && dy == 0) {
                dy = SIZE;
                dx = 0;
            }
            if(left && dx == 0) {
                dx = -SIZE;
                dy = 0;
            }
            if(right && dy == 0) {
                dx = SIZE;
                dy = 0;
            }

            if(dy!=0 || dx!= 0) {
                for( int i = snake.size() -1 ;i > 0; i-- ) {
                    snake.get(i).setPosition(snake.get(i-1).getX(),snake.get(i-1).getY());
                }
            }
            head.move(dx,dy);

            if(head.getX() < 0 ) head.setX(WIDTH);
            if(head.getY() < 0 ) head.setY(HEIGHT);
            if(head.getX() > WIDTH) head.setX(0);
            if(head.getY() > HEIGHT) head.setY(0);
    }

    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  I would imagine that 95% of this code is not relevant to your problem.  Please create a [**Minimal**, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: Edited, thank you @JoeC

Comment: Well as suggested by @FredK , you are not invoking the `JPanel` properly but instead  you are initializing a blocking thread. So i suppose that if you post your main method we might trace the problem.

Comment: That is still way too much code, and the community does not have the time to go through it.  Remember, we are volunteering our time, and what we ask in return is that you put some effort in yourself.  Please spend some time in the debugger, narrow down the problem to no more than 20 lines, and then if you still need help, come back with those 20 lines.

Answer (score -2):

Without showing a main() method, everything we say is just a guess. But one problem is that your run() method is an infinite loop that blocks the event thread.

Comment: This isn't really an answer to the question.  If you need clarification, please post as a comment instead.